# Searches on SVN history through Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, svn

In Eclipse IDE:

1. Is there any way to show the whole SVN history of a directory (a java package in fact)? If I right click -> Team -> Show History it only shows me a couple of days back. Is this limitation due to SVN server configuration?
2. Is there any way to show the whole SVN history for a given user (for a given branch)?

Thanks!

EDIT: here's a screenshot of available options. I'm using "Show History" as stated above.

[image]

Comment: Ok, I got it: Window -> Preferences -> Team -> SVN -> Default number of log messages.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

1. The server has no such limitations
   There should be an icon or so which says "Show all", cause usually the history view shows only the last 25 revisions in the history. For a detailed description take a look [here](http://www.eclipse.org/subversive/documentation/teamSupport/history_view.php).
   In the image you see on the right side the icons for "Next 25" and "Get all".
   [image]

Comment: Thanks, but there's no "Show All" option, and I already Googled this (that link was promising but actually did not help, that screenshot are revisions of a given file).

Comment: The is no difference between the history of a file and the history of a directory. Updated answer appropriately.

Comment: I know there's no difference, but I didn't notice the "History" buttons. Thanks!

Comment: Maybe a better icon would help people find this button easier

Answer (score 2):

Window -> Preferences -> Team -> SVN -> Default number of log messages.  Or you can press the ">|" button to see the complete history.